# How to Center Text in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have some code:

```
# draw text
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
text = font.render("You win!", True, BLACK)
screen.blit(text, [SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2])
```

How can I get the text's width and height, so I can center text like this:

```
screen.blit(text, [SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - text_w / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - text_h / 2])
```

If this is not possible, what is another way ?
I've found [this](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/tom/games2.html) example, but I didn't really understand it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the dimensions of the rendered text image using `text.get_rect()`, which returns a [Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object with `width` and `height` attributes, among others (see the linked documentation for a full list). I.e. you can simply do `text.get_rect().width`.

Answer (score 46):

You can always just center the text rectangle when you grab it:

```
# draw text
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
text = font.render("You win!", True, BLACK)
text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

just another option

Comment: This is the best answer of the question.

Comment: Good, and you can get the center width and height with SURF.get_width // 2 and SURF.height // 2

Answer (score 8):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

Get the text rectangle and place the center of the text rectangle on the center of the window rectangle:

```py
text_rect = text.get_rect(center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2))
```

You can even get the center of the window from the display *Surface* :

```py
text_rect = text.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center)
```

Or with the use of [`pygame.display.get_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html):

```py
text_rect = text.get_rect(center = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center)
```

A *Surface* can be drawn on another *Surface* using the [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method. The second argument is either a tuple (*x*, *y*) representing the upper left corner or a rectangle. With a rectangle, only the upper left corner of the rectangle is taken into account. Therefore you can pass the text rectangle directly to `blit`:

```py
screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import pygame.font

pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
text = font.render('Hello World', True, (255, 0, 0))

window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 100))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 4):

To simplify the use of text, I use this function (to center it the x is not useful)

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
WIDTH = HEIGHT = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 14)


def write(text, x, y, color="Coral",):
    text = font.render(text, 1, pygame.Color(color))
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(WIDTH//2, y))
    return text, text_rect

text, text_rect = write("Hello", 10, 10) # this will be centered anyhow, but at 10 height
loop = 1
while loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = 0
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rendered text is blitted on a transparent surface in Pygame. So you can use the methods of the surface class described here:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_width

So for you the following would work:

text.get_width()

text.get_height()

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but I recently came across this problem when making a simple python game with pygame so I wanted to share my solution as well.

```
def draw_text(_window: pygame.Surface, text: str, font: pygame.font.Font, aa: bool, fg: str, bg: str,
              x: int | float, y: int | float, centered_x: bool, centered_y: bool) -> None:
    """
    Function to draw text on window

    :param _window: window to draw text on (pygame.Surface)
    :param text: text to draw on window (str)
    :param font: font to render the text with (pygame.font.Font)
    :param aa: use antialiasing (bool)
    :param fg: foreground color (str)
    :param bg: background color (str)
    :param x: x coordinate of window to draw text on (int | float)
    :param y: y coordinate of window to draw text on (int | float)
    :param centered_x: center in the x-axis (bool)
    :param centered_y: center in the y-axis (bool)
    :return: None
    """

    text = font.render(text, aa, fg, bg)
    text_position = x, y

    if centered_x or centered_y:
        text_position = text.get_rect()
    if centered_x:
        text_position.y += y
        text_position.centerx = _window.get_rect().centerx
    if centered_y:
        text_position.x += x
        text_position.centery = _window.get_rect().centery

    _window.blit(text, text_position)
```

The function has additional functionality that I explain in the docstring (it can be used for a wide variety of options not just centering x, y axis for text in pygame).