# Pygame: Centering text system font text

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

**I have read this post about centering text:**
[Pygame - How to Center Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982907/python-library-pygame-centering-text)

However instead of importing text from a file:

`font = pygame.font.Font("example_font.tff", 25)`

I want to use a font from the users system

`font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("comicsansms", 0)`

using the freetype module as I think it makes rendering to various sizes easier (like when the user resizes the window)
`font.render_to(surface, pos, ..., size=int(surface.get_height()/2))`

Im not sure how to set a value for pos where the text will be shown in the center of the surface, as I can't `.get_rect()` or anything to get the dimensions of the text

**Possible solutions?**
Getting the dimensions of the text
Using System Fonts with `pygame.font.Font()`

Thanks!

Comment: render the font first then adjust the position after. So use `txt = font.render(text, antialiasing, color) -> Surface` and then `text_rect = txt.get_rect(center=centered_pos)`. this creates a surface in memory and you will still need to blit it. In order to get the size of a loaded font just use `font.size("txt")`

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the position "pos" that it needs to be rendered to, because I'm not sure how to get the dimensions of the rendered text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pygame.freetype.Font.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.get_rect) to get a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object with the size of the text. Note, `freetype.Font` and `freetype.SysFont` have the same interface:

```py
text = "Hello World"
text_size = 50
```

```py
text_rect = font.get_rect(text, size = text_size)
text_rect.center = surface.get_rect().center 

font.render_to(surface, text_rect, text, color, size = text_size)
```

---

Minimal examaple:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 200))

def drawTextCentered(surface, text, text_size, color):
    text_rect = font.get_rect(text, size = 50)
    text_rect.center = surface.get_rect().center 
    font.render_to(surface, text_rect, text, color, size = 50)  

font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("comicsansms", 0) 

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)
    drawTextCentered(window, "Hello World", 50, (255, 0, 0))  
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Im not using freetype.Font, im using freetype.SysFont and I don't believe that SysFont has the method .get_rect()

Comment: @k-shar See the documentation: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.get_rect. I've provided the link in the answer. You just have to read the answer.

Comment: @k-shar `freetype.Font` and `freetype.SysFont` have the same interface