# Pygame rect.centre attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, pygame, rect

So here is two parts of pygame python code:

```
a = self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))
print(a.topleft)
```

The output of this code is :

```
(200, 189)
```

Another pygame code:

```
a = self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)).center
print(a)
```

The output of this code:

```
(234, 213)
```

Note: `The value of self.x is 200 and self.y is 200`

So now my question is how after we put .center after the pygame `rect object or the variable a` when i print the value of a it changes and what does a .center after a pygame rect object do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.  The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the top left of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `topleft`.

The [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has various virtual attriubtes:

> The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to move and align the Rect:
>
> ```
> x,y
> top, left, bottom, right
> topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
> midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
> center, centerx, centery
> size, width, height
> w,h
> ```

You actually set the top left corner of a rectangle, the size of the image:

> ```py
> self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))
> ```

Finally, you get the center point of this rectangle by reading the `center` attribute. Since the size of the image is not 0, the `center` differs from the `topleft`.

Comment: ok so the centre will be for x will be self.x + self.img.get_width()/2

Comment: @Rajarshi Yes. Reading the documentation will clear up all of your questions: [`pygame.Rect´](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Comment: But i have a question why we would use the .centre

Comment: @Rajarshi You use center when you want to set or get the center of the image. e.g. When you want to center a rectangle on the screen.

Comment: OK but we can simply get the center of a image by self.x + self.img.get_width()/2

Comment: @Rajarshi Yes you can, but you'll need more code. See for example [How to Center Text in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982907/pygame-how-to-center-text/64660744#64660744) or [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144)