# how can i center the numbers in the two grids?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

this is the program of the game, it contains everything but i need help to center the numbers inside the grids, i did some attempts i put them in comments, please help me

imports of my program

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
```

constructor of the class

```
class Py2048:
    def __init__(self):
        self.N = 4

        self.grid1 = np.zeros((self.N, self.N), dtype=int)   #initialiasation de la grid avec des 0
        self.grid2 = np.zeros((self.N, self.N), dtype=int) #initialiasation

        self.cellSize = 70
        self.gap = 3
        self.windowBgColor = (187, 173, 160)
        self.blockSize = self.cellSize + self.gap * 2
        self.W = 700
        self.H = self.W

        pygame.init()

        pygame.display.set_caption("2048")

        pygame.font.init()
        self.myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.W, self.H))
```

adding a new number to the grids

```
    def new_number(self, k=1):
        free_poss1 = list(zip(*np.where(self.grid1 == 0)))  #position de la grid
        free_poss2 = list(zip(*np.where(self.grid2 == 0)))

        
        for pos in random.sample(free_poss1, k=k):         #random 2 ou 4
                if random.random() < .1:
                    self.grid1[pos] = 4
                else:
                    self.grid1[pos] = 2

        for pos in random.sample(free_poss2, k=k):         #random 2 ou 4
                if random.random() < .1:
                    self.grid2[pos] = 4
                else:
                    self.grid2[pos] = 2
```

```
    @staticmethod
    def _get_nums(this):
        this_n = this[this != 0]
        this_n_sum = []
        skip = False
        for j in range(len(this_n)):
            if skip:
                skip = False
                continue
            if j != len(this_n) - 1 and this_n[j] == this_n[j + 1]:
                new_n = this_n[j] * 2
                skip = True
            else:
                new_n = this_n[j]

            this_n_sum.append(new_n)
        return np.array(this_n_sum)

    def make_move(self, move):       #move
        for i in range(self.N):
            if move in 'lr':
                this1 = self.grid1[i, :]
                this2 = self.grid2[i, :]
            else:
                this1 = self.grid1[:, i]
                this2 = self.grid2[:, i]

            flipped = False
            if move in 'rd':
                flipped = True
                this1 = this1[::-1]
                this2 = this2[::-1]

            this_n1 = self._get_nums(this1)
            this_n2 = self._get_nums(this2)

            new_this1 = np.zeros_like(this1)
            new_this1[:len(this_n1)] = this_n1
            new_this2 = np.zeros_like(this2)
            new_this2[:len(this_n2)] = this_n2


            if flipped:
                new_this1 = new_this1[::-1]
                new_this2 = new_this2[::-1]

            if move in 'lr':
                self.grid1[i, :] = new_this1
                self.grid2[i, :] = new_this2
            else:
                self.grid1[:, i] = new_this1
                self.grid2[:, i] = new_this2
```

this is where i have the problem, when i draw the two grids i dont know how to center the numbers in them

```
    def draw_game(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.windowBgColor)
        for i in range(self.N):
            rectY = self.blockSize * i + self.gap
            for j in range(self.N):

                n1 = self.grid1[i][j]
                n2 = self.grid2[i][j]

                rectX = 200 + self.blockSize * j + self.gap
              
                pygame.draw.rect(
                    self.screen,
                    (255, 255, 255),
                    pygame.Rect(rectX, 40 + rectY, self.cellSize, self.cellSize),
                    border_radius = 6
                )
                pygame.draw.rect(
                    self.screen,
                    (255, 255, 255),
                    pygame.Rect(rectX, 360 + rectY, self.cellSize, self.cellSize),
                    border_radius = 6
                )
              
            if n1 == 0 and n2 == 0:
                    continue
            text_surface1 = self.myfont.render(f'{n1}', True, (0, 0, 0))
            text_rect1 = text_surface1.get_rect(center=(rectX  ,
                                                          rectY ))
            self.screen.blit(text_surface1, text_rect1)

            # text_surface2 = self.myfont.render(f'{n2}', True, (0, 0, 0))
            # text_rect2 = text_surface2.get_rect(center=(rectX  ,
            #                                               360 + rectY ))
            # self.screen.blit(text_surface2, text_rect2)
```

```
            
    @staticmethod
    def wait_for_key():
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    return 'q'
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_UP:
                        return 'u'
                    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        return 'r'
                    elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                        return 'l'
                    elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                        return 'd'
                    elif event.key == K_q or event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        return 'q'

   
    def play(self):
        self.new_number(k=2)

        while True:
            self.draw_game()
            pygame.display.flip()
            cmd = self.wait_for_key()
            if cmd == 'q':
                break

            old_grid1 = self.grid1.copy()
            old_grid2 = self.grid2.copy()
            self.make_move(cmd)
            print(game.grid1)
            print(game.grid2)
           
            if all((self.grid1 == old_grid1).flatten()) and all((self.grid2 == old_grid2).flatten()):
                continue
            self.new_number()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Py2048()
    game.play()
```

this is the main code for the modified 2048 game that i wanna create

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Center Text in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982907/pygame-how-to-center-text/64660744#64660744). When calculating the text rectangle, the center of the text rectangle must be set by the center of the grid. Store the tile rectangle in a variable and use it to set the center of the text rectangle:

```py
for i in range(self.N):
    rectY = self.blockSize * i + self.gap
    for j in range(self.N):

        n1 = self.grid1[i][j]
        n2 = self.grid2[i][j]
        rectX = 200 + self.blockSize * j + self.gap

        tile_rect1 = pygame.Rect(rectX, 40 + rectY, self.cellSize, self.cellSize)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), tile_rect1, border_radius = 6)

        tile_rect2 = pygame.Rect(rectX, 360 + rectY, self.cellSize, self.cellSize),
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), tile_rect2, border_radius = 6) 

        if n1 == 0 and n2 == 0:
            continue
            
        text_surface1 = self.myfont.render(f'{n1}', True, (0, 0, 0))
        text_rect1 = text_surface1.get_rect(center = tile_rect1.center)
        self.screen.blit(text_surface1, text_rect1)

        text_surface2 = self.myfont.render(f'{n2}', True, (0, 0, 0))
        text_rect2 = text_surface2.get_rect(center = tile_rect2.center)
        self.screen.blit(text_surface2, text_rect2)
```